# I'm not able to configure my virtual host in XAMPP and also I want to change my root htdocs directory to a different folder

Tags: xampp, localhost

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot C:/Users/user/Desktop/WebsiteDesign
ServerName testproject

<Directory "C:/Users/user/Desktop/WebsiteDesign">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have gone to C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and changed the values.

After making the changes I went to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host

Also following all these steps I stopped and started Apace Service from the XAMPP control panel. Still it's not working. I have also given the httpd-vhost.conf file. Can someone please guide me to configure step by step. my xampp version is 3.2.2

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry 
 about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
#NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>



NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot C:/Users/user/Desktop/WebsiteDesign
ServerName testproject

<Directory "C:/Users/user/Desktop/WebsiteDesign">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: In that first screenshot only a single virtual host is defined. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I know that I asked about multiple host but I'm defining a single host. But my question is that I m not able to set the host and its showing forbidden.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to set the host"? You need to be more precise for us to understand what _exactly_ you struggle with.

Comment: Actually I'm not able to rephrase my question. The default directory is htdocs. but i want in a different folder. And at the same time i should be able to host my different folders.

Comment: ok i would give you the configuration files

Comment: What version of Apache are you running? They look like 2.2 configuration files, I think you need 2.4. I guess you need `Require All` - [see this](https://serverfault.com/questions/549517/what-does-apaches-require-all-granted-really-do). Your question still needs some work though - what does "not working" mean **exactly**? Does the server not start? Does it start but the vhost is pointing to the wrong place? Do you get any errors on start-up? Any errors in your logs?

Comment: I managed myself. now it's working fine. Thank you all